# Increasing arrow sizes in a Custom List Batch View

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-list-actions

I have a custom list, which I am displaying documents in batches of 10. Is there anyway of increasing the size of the arrows? They are small, and I am using this in a mobile / touch environment.

I am using SPD2013 OP.

[image: Arrows]

Comment: Is it SharePoint online or on-prem?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013 On Prem